# Combining -v flag and -A flag in grep

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I need to search a file for a string, remove any line that contains the string, and also remove the two lines following any line that contains the string. I was hoping I could accomplish this using something like this...

```
$ grep -v -A 2 two temp.txt
one
five
$
```

...but unfortunately this did not work. Is there a simple I can do this with grep or another shell command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works both with GNU sed and with OS X.

```sh
$ sed '/two/{N;N;d;}' temp.txt
one
five
```

- find line matching `two`
- read in two more lines
- delete them

Comment: Both your answer and @JohnKugelman's are concise, they both work on GNU/Linux, and neither work on OS X (not a huge deal for me for this particular task). For providing a brief explanation of the syntax, the accepted answer goes to you. Thanks.

Comment: Add a semicolon after the d and. Enforce the brace and it should work on MacOS X too.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/two/,+2d' temp.txt
```

This uses two-address syntax (`addr1,addr2`) to match lines with the word two (`/two/`) plus the two lines after (`+2`). The `d` command deletes those lines.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe they're using a older, non-GNU sed, without the `+number` option. But since it works (and I dislike drive-by downvoters), here's a vote to reverse it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `awk`, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'one
two
three
four
five' | awk '/two/ {skip=3} skip>0 {skip--;next} {print}'

one
five
```

It basically starts a counter of lines to throw away (3) whenever it finds the `two` string on a line. It then throws those lines away until the skip counter reaches zero. Any line that isn't marked for skipping is printed.

Comment: This has the advantage of handling `one two three two three four five` → `one five` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with Perl:

```
$ perl -ne'if (/two/){$x=<>;$x=<>;}else{print}' temp.txt 
one
five
```

The `-n` is an implicit loop over the input.  If you match `/two/`, then read the next two lines, otherwise print the line you're on.

The problem is, however, that if you had the third or fourth lines matched /two/, then you would still get the same output.  @paxdiablo's solution is more complete.  But mine's more Q&D.